# How can I load the address of a symbol by absolute addressing in RISC-V 64?

Tags: assembly, riscv

I have a symbol `_symbol` and need to load its absolute address. But if I write

```
lui t1, %hi(_symbol)
addi t1, t1, %lo(_symbol)
```

the linker complaints just like this

```
relocation R_RISCV_HI20 out of range: -2251799813160077 is not in [-524288, 524287]
```

My question is: how can I load the address of a symbol by ABSOLUTE addressing in RISC-V asm (without GOT, since there is no dynamic linker)?

A similar question is here:
[How can I load the absolute address of a symbol larger than 0x7FFFFFFF in RiscV64 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65398986/how-can-i-load-the-absolute-address-of-a-symbol-larger-than-0x7fffffff-in-riscv6)
But the solution given above does not work for me, because the load address and the destination address are also very far (> 2^32) from each other.

Comment: Did you try looking at compiler output, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/359rf7PM1?  RV64 GCC uses an `lla t1, symbol` pseudo-instruction with `-O3 -mcmodel=medany`, vs. `la` with `-fPIC`.  Or RV64 clang uses a PC-relative load from the GOT with `-fPIC`.

Comment: @PeterCordes No. I need load a ABSOLTE address.

Comment: I don't know why using ABSOLUTE address is a must. However, if so, saving the address at a not so far memory location and using memory operating instruction, `ld`, is an option.

Comment: @Wanghz Because the load address of my program is not the same with that in the linker script, so I need to enable paging and use the absolute address of symbols in my program before entering the main.

Comment: The GOT holds absolute addresses.  It's reachable with PC-relative addressing.  But anyway, that's just *one* of the multiple options I mentioned.  Do none of them assemble to 64-bit absolute?  I guessed `-mcmodel=medany` would; it has to support large static arrays so static data can't be assumed to be in range for PC-relative directly.

Comment: 32-bit ARM assemblers placed the address (a 32-bit word) as data after the code and loaded the 32-bit value using a PC-relative load instruction. You could do it the same way and place a 64-bit constant (the address) after the code. I have never worked with RISC-V, but the combination of `AUIPC` and `LD` should be able to load the 64-bit constant.

Comment: @PeterCordes No. 1. Both `mcmodel=medany` and `mcmodel=large` make no difference, 2. bytes in .got are zeros maybe because I just simply `objcopy` to translate elf to binary.

Comment: Ok, the fact that you don't have a dynamic linker to fill GOT entries is probably something you should mention in your question.  Future readers with a similar problem for large static data in a normal program under an OS might want to do it that way.  But anyway, Martin's idea would still work: manually assemble a 64-bit absolute address as data somewhere near enough you can load it with `auipc` / `ld`.  Otherwise IDK what strategy for constructing large addresses the RISC-V ABI assumes for its design of the relocations available.

Comment: Just to be clear,  `-mcmodel=large` definitely won't help assembling existing asm.  My suggestion was to compile a C function using that option, and look at what instructions the compiler used.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Yes, it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to @MartinRosenau's suggestion: place a 64-bit constant (the address) after the code. The solution can be written as follows:

```
# Use load instruction get address of _symbol
ld t1, symbol_addr
jr t1
...
# A large pc for _symbol
_symbol:
    nop
    ...
.data
# symbol_addr equals to the address of _symbol
symbol_addr: .dowrd _symbol
```

The data **symbol_addr** will be calculated automatically as the address of _symbol, which maybe a large address, then use "ld" instruction to load the symbol_addr, register 't1' equals to symbol_addr and "jr" instruction will works.